# Laravel - When to use ->get()

Tags: laravel

I'm confused as to when `->get()` in Laravel...

E.G. `DB::table('users')->find(1)` doesn't need ->get() to retrieve the results, neither does `User::find(1)`

The laravel docs say "...execute the query using the get or first method..."

I've read the Fluent Query Builder and Eloquent docs but don't understand when the usage of get() is required...

Thanks for the help [image]

Answer (score 24):

Since the `find()` function will always use the primary key for the table, the need for `get()` is not necessary. Because you can't narrow your selection down and that's why it will always just try to get that record and return it.

But when you're using the Fluent Query Builder you can nest conditions as such:

```
$userQuery = DB::table('users');
$userQuery->where('email', '=', 'foo@bar.com');
$userQuery->or_where('email', '=', 'bar@foo.com');
```

This allows you to add conditions throughout your code until you actually want to fetch them, and then you would call the `get()` function.

```
// Done with building the query
$users = $userQuery->get();
```

Comment: Thanks nerdklers, I really appreciate the reply! So is `get()` **only** not required when you use `->find()` ... I can't find any docs on when it's usage is required... Also is ->get() usage not required in Eloquent or is get() usage the same in Eloquent and the Fluent Query Builder? Thanks for the help ![ ][1]

    [1]: http://i6.minus.com/jLj4oKVAVXP8l.png

Comment: Think of it like this: when you don't exactly know what a query will return then you need to use `get()`. For example you can't use it with `all()` since you **know** that it will return all the records and no further conditions can be applied. It's the same with `find()` since you know it will only try to fetch one record.

Comment: @nerdklers - nice clarification. You might think about adding it to the main answer.

Comment: nerdklers: Thanks for the answer, you really did clear up its usage.

Answer (score 16):

- For `find(n)`, you retrieve a row based on the **primary key** which is 'n'.
- For `first()`, you retrieve the **first row** among all rows that fit the where clauses.
- For `get()`, you retrieve **all the rows** that fit the where clauses. (Please note that loops are required to access all the rows or you will get some errors).

Answer (score 2):

`find` returns one row from the database and represent it as a fluent / eloquent object. e.g. `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 3` is equivalent to `DB::table('users')->find(3);`

`get` returns an array of objects. e.g. `SELECT * FROM users WHERE created_at > '2014-10-12'` is equivalent to `DB::table('users')->where('created_at', '>', '2014-10-12')->get()` will return an array of objects containing users where the created at field is newer than 4014-10-12.

Answer (score 1):

The `get()` method will give you all the values from the database that meet your parameters where as `first()` gets you just the first result. You use `find()` and `findOrFail()` when you are searching for a key. This is how I use them:

When I want all data from a table I use the all() method

```
Model::all();
```

When I want to find by the primary key:

```
  Model::find(1)->first();
```

Or

```
 Model::findOrFail(1)->first();
```

This will work if there is a row with a primary key of one. It should only retrieve one row so I use `first()` instead of `get()`. Remember if you deleted the row that used key 1, or don't have data in your table, your `find(1)` will fail.

When I am looking for specific data as in a where clause:

```
Model::where('field', '=', 'value')->get();
```

When I want only the first value of the data in the where clause.

```
Model::where('field', '=', 'value')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need to understand is that get() return a collection(note that one object can be in the collection but it still a collection) why first() returns the first object from the result of the query(that is it returns an object)
#Take_away
Get() return a collection first() return an object

Answer (score 0):

You can use get() method with latest() method to get the latest record that were recently added to your table
For example

```
$user=Student::latest()->get();
```

return all the data in descending order