# Laravel find:: returning all rows

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, orm, laravel-5.1

I am using :
 `dd(User::find(1)->get());` on a table that has 4994 rows, and the above query returns all the rows.
But when I do :

`User::where('id',1)->with('groups')->get()`

, I get the right row(just one)

User table has a column called id, which is primary key.

I am using *Laravel Framework version 5.1.31 (LTS)*

Could anybody tell me what the problem is ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you don't need to attach `get()` with `find()` method. find is the shortest and simplest method to return single record without attaching `get()`.

just do this, you will get only single record.

```
dd(User::find(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `find()` function will always use the primary key for the table, the need for `get()` is not necessary. Because you can't narrow your selection down using `primary key` and that's why it will always just try to get that record and return it.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13698488/4807414